# Typescript conditional typings strange error case

Tags: typescript, typescript-conditional-types

Conditional typing in Typescript is not very intuitive. The code bellow returns an error in the Typescript playground. Can someone explain why since this seems like a perfect easy example for the conditional typings.

```
function process<T extends string | null>(text: T): T extends string ? string : null {
  return text;
}

//Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : null'.
//Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : null'.
//Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : null'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is not able to narrow the return type of a function with conditional types, which has parameters defined as a union.

```
function process<T extends string | null>(text: T): T extends string ? string : null {
  // the problem here is that type guard can't narrow over the type parameter
  if (typeof text === 'string') {
      return text; // error
  }

  return null; // error
}
```

The best you can do is to `return text as any;` and go on with your life. The alternative here is to use overloads to accomplish what you want.

Comment: relevant GitHub issue for those interested: [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912)